# Group on two columns and calculate net total SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am finding it difficult to modify an existing SQL query to group records on two columns. Following is the query which retrieves records from multiple tables by joining:

```
SELECT 
    InM.invm_No AS DocNo,
    InM.docs_DocCode,
    D.doctyp_Desc AS DocType,
    L.loc_Desc AS Site,
    InM.sup_Code AS Supplier,
    InD.invd_Qty,
    InD.invd_Rate
FROM 
    [SI_InventoryMaster] InM 
INNER JOIN  
    [SI_DocType] AS D ON InM.doctyp_Code = D.doctyp_Code 
INNER JOIN  
    SI_Supplier S ON InM.sup_Code = S.sup_Code 
INNER JOIN  
    [SI_InventoryDetail] AS InD ON InD.invm_No = InM.invm_No 
                                AND InM.invm_verified = 1 
                                AND InM.docs_DocCode = 'GRN' 
                                AND MONTH (InM.invm_Date) = 12 
                                AND YEAR(InM.invm_date) = 2013 
INNER JOIN 
    SI_Location L ON InD.loc_code = L.loc_Code  
ORDER BY 
    InM.invm_No
```

Which results the following:

[image]

I need to group records "by DocNo by Site" and find total amount for each site. Total amount will be last column in this resultset and it is net of product of `InD.invd_Qty` and `InD.invd_Rate` for each site.

For DocNo: 00000030, there are 4 records of CWS Store Site, so its total amount would be calculated as: 7684.999+7684.999+3000+3000=21369.998

In this particular example, modified query should return following resultset:

[image]

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I am not able to group these records on two columns!!

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping on all the columns associated with those two columns.  Something like:

```
SELECT InM.invm_No AS DocNo, InM.docs_DocCode, D.doctyp_Desc AS DocType,
       L.loc_Desc AS Site, InM.sup_Code AS Supplier,
       sum(InD.invd_Qty),
       sum(InD.invd_Rate)
FROM [SI_InventoryMaster] InM INNER JOIN  
     [SI_DocType] AS D
     ON InM.doctyp_Code = D.doctyp_Code INNER JOIN  
     SI_Supplier S
     ON InM.sup_Code = S.sup_Code INNER JOIN  
     [SI_InventoryDetail] AS InD
     ON InD.invm_No = InM.invm_No AND
        InM.invm_verified = 1 AND
        InM.docs_DocCode = 'GRN' AND
        MONTH (InM.invm_Date) = 12 AND
        YEAR(InM.invm_date) = 2013 INNER JOIN 
     SI_Location L
     ON InD.loc_code = L.loc_Code  
GROUP BY InM.invm_No AS DocNo, InM.docs_DocCode, D.doctyp_Desc AS DocType,
         L.loc_Desc AS Site, InM.sup_Code AS Supplier;
```

Comment: I need to multiply rate and qty values for each site and then find sum of those products for each site. you are just calculating the sum only.